# Scrolling thumb in div didn't work on firefox

Tags: css, html, scroll

this is my permanent scrolling thumb and its works great on chrome, but not on firefox
Any ideas how can I do it on Firefox
thanks.

Here is my [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AhIrg)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't have a feature to allow for the scrollbar to be changed with CSS yet. It has been requested, but atm only webkit browsers allow it.

Something look at would probably be a jQuery alternative such as [perfect scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) which i've used before and is quite good. Not as good as an inbuilt version like in chrome but it does the job for now.